# Blank screen output when Parsing data from Json Code extracted from a website Api

Tags: java, android, json

I always get a blank screen after running the code below.I have created a custom array adapter and a custom class too but it was not giving any blank screen when I was using an array list to display items in a list view. but now I want to test parsing from using Json data now it is giving a blank screen why please help

```
    import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Helper methods related to requesting and receiving earthquake data from USGS.
 */
public final class QueryUtils {

    /** Sample JSON response for a USGS query */
    private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"metadata\":{\"generated\":1462295443000,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10\",\"title\":\"USGS Earthquakes\",\"status\":200,\"api\":\"1.5.2\",\"limit\":10,\"offset\":1,\"count\":10},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.2,\"place\":\"88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\",\"time\":1454124312220,\"updated\":1460674294040,\"tz\":720,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004vvx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004vvx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":2,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":5.82,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":798,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004vvx\",\"ids\":\",at00o1qxho,pt16030050,us20004vvx,gcmt20160130032510,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.958,\"rms\":1.19,\"gap\":17,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.2 - 88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[158.5463,53.9776,177]},\"id\":\"us20004vvx\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\",\"time\":1453777820750,\"updated\":1460156775040,\"tz\":600,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004uks\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004uks&format=geojson\",\"felt\":null,\"cdi\":null,\"mmi\":4.1,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":572,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004uks\",\"ids\":\",us20004uks,gcmt20160126031023,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.537,\"rms\":0.74,\"gap\":25,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[153.2454,-5.2952,26]},\"id\":\"us20004uks\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.3,\"place\":\"50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\",\"time\":1453695722730,\"updated\":1460156773040,\"tz\":0,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gy9\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gy9&format=geojson\",\"felt\":117,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":5.28,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":695,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gy9\",\"ids\":\",us10004gy9,gcmt20160125042203,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.201,\"rms\":0.92,\"gap\":20,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.3 - 50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-3.6818,35.6493,12]},\"id\":\"us10004gy9\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.1,\"place\":\"86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\",\"time\":1453631430230,\"updated\":1460156770040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gqp\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gqp&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1816,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":6.6,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":1496,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gqp\",\"ids\":\",at00o1gd6r,us10004gqp,ak12496371,gcmt20160124103030,\",\"sources\":\",at,us,ak,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,trump-origin,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.72,\"rms\":2.11,\"gap\":19,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.1 - 86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-153.4051,59.6363,129]},\"id\":\"us10004gqp\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.6,\"place\":\"215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\",\"time\":1453399617650,\"updated\":1459963829040,\"tz\":-420,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004g4l\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004g4l&format=geojson\",\"felt\":11,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":3.92,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":673,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004g4l\",\"ids\":\",at00o1bebo,pt16021050,us10004g4l,gcmt20160121180659,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.413,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":74,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.6 - 215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-106.9337,18.8239,10]},\"id\":\"us10004g4l\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.7,\"place\":\"52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\",\"time\":1452741933640,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":51,\"cdi\":5.8,\"mmi\":6.45,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":720,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebx\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebx,pt16014050,at00o0xauk,gcmt20160114032534,\",\"sources\":\",us,pt,at,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",associate,cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.281,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.7 - 52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[142.781,41.9723,46]},\"id\":\"us10004ebx\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\",\"time\":1452741928270,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":-240,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebw\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebw&format=geojson\",\"felt\":3,\"cdi\":2.2,\"mmi\":2.21,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":573,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebw\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebw,gcmt20160114032528,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":5.492,\"rms\":1.04,\"gap\":16,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-63.3288,-19.7597,582.56]},\"id\":\"us10004ebw\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.2,\"place\":\"74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\",\"time\":1452532083920,\"updated\":1459304875040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004djn\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004djn&format=geojson\",\"felt\":8,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":3.74,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":594,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004djn\",\"ids\":\",us10004djn,gcmt20160111170803,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.139,\"rms\":0.96,\"gap\":33,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.2 - 74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[141.0867,44.4761,238.81]},\"id\":\"us10004djn\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.5,\"place\":\"227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\",\"time\":1452530285900,\"updated\":1459304874040,\"tz\":480,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004dj5\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004dj5&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":7.5,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":650,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004dj5\",\"ids\":\",at00o0srjp,pt16011050,us10004dj5,gcmt20160111163807,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":3.144,\"rms\":0.72,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.5 - 227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[126.8621,3.8965,13]},\"id\":\"us10004dj5\"},\n" +
            "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6,\"place\":\"Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\",\"time\":1451986454620,\"updated\":1459202978040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004bgk\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004bgk&format=geojson\",\"felt\":0,\"cdi\":1,\"mmi\":0,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":554,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004bgk\",\"ids\":\",us10004bgk,gcmt20160105093415,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":30.75,\"rms\":0.67,\"gap\":71,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.0 - Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-136.2603,-54.2906,10]},\"id\":\"us10004bgk\"}],\"bbox\":[-153.4051,-54.2906,10,158.5463,59.6363,582.56]}";


    /**
     * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtils} object.
     * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
     * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryUtils is not needed).
     */
    private QueryUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * Return a list of {@link Earthquake} objects that has been built up from
     * parsing a JSON response.
     */
    public static ArrayList<Earthquake> extractEarthquakes() {

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
        ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();

        // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {

            //  Parse the response given by the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE string and
            // build up a list of Earthquake objects with the corresponding data.

                JSONObject BaseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
                // Getting JSON Array Node
                JSONArray earthquakeArray = BaseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("Features");
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < earthquakeArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject currentEarthquake = earthquakeArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject properties= currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("properties");
                    String magnitude=properties.getString("mag");
                    String location=properties.getString("place");
                    String time=properties.getString("time");
                    Earthquake earthquake= new Earthquake(magnitude,location,time);
                    earthquakes.add(earthquake);



                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
                // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
                // with the message from the exception.
                Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
            }

            // Return the list of earthquakes
            return earthquakes;
        }

    }
```

here is my main activity code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

        // Create a fake list of earthquake locations.
        ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = QueryUtils.extractEarthquakes();

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create an {@link EarthquakeAdapter}, whose data source is a list of
        // {@link Earthquake}s. The adapter knows how to create list item views for each item
        // in the list.
        EarthquakeAdapter quakeAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(this,earthquakes);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(quakeAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of custom class I made.

```
public class Earthquake {


    //Magnitude of earthquake (e.g. 7.5,5.5,6.4 etc)
        private String mMagnitude;

        //Place of Earthquake (Kolkata, Delhi etc)
        private String mPlace;

        // Date Of the occurrence
        private String mDate;

        /*
        * Create a new Earthquake object.
        *
        * @param vName is the name of the Android version (e.g. Gingerbread)
        * @param vNumber is the corresponding Android version number (e.g. 2.3-2.7)
        * @param image is drawable reference ID that corresponds to the Android version
        * */
        public Earthquake(String eMagnitude, String ePlace, String eDate)
        {
            mMagnitude = eMagnitude;
            mPlace = ePlace;
            mDate = eDate;
        }

        /**
         * Get value of magnitude
         */
        public String getMagnitude() {
            return mMagnitude;
        }

        /**
         * Get the place of occurrence
         */
        public String getPlace() {
            return mPlace;
        }

        /**
         * Get the Date of occurrence
         */
        public String  getDate() {
            return mDate;
        }


    }
```

here is the Custom array adapter.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Atanu on 25-06-2017.
 */

/*
* {@link EarthquakeAdapter} is an {@link ArrayAdapter} that can provide the layout for each list
* based on a data source, which is a list of {@link Earthquake} objects.
* */
public class EarthquakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Earthquake> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * This is our own custom constructor (it doesn't mirror a superclass constructor).
     * The context is used to inflate the layout file, and the list is the data we want
     * to populate into the lists.
     *
     * @param context        The current context. Used to inflate the layout file.
     * @param earthquakes A List of Earthquake objects to display in a list
     */
    public EarthquakeAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for three TextViews , the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0, earthquakes);
    }

    /**
     * Provides a view for an AdapterView (ListView, GridView, etc.)
     *
     * @param position The position in the list of data that should be displayed in the
     *                 list item view.
     * @param convertView The recycled view to populate.
     * @param parent The parent ViewGroup that is used for inflation.
     * @return The View for the position in the AdapterView.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link Earthquake} object located at this position in the list
        Earthquake currentEarthquake = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID mag
        TextView magTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.mag);
        // Get the magnitude from the current Earthquake object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        magTextView.setText(currentEarthquake.getMagnitude());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID place
        TextView placeTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.place);
        // Get the place of occurrence from the current Earthquake object and
        // set this text on the number TextView
        placeTextView.setText(currentEarthquake.getPlace());

        // Find the Date of occurrence in the list_item.xml layout with the ID date
        TextView dateTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // Get the Date of occurrence from the current Earthquake object and
        // set the date to TextView
        dateTextView.setText(currentEarthquake.getDate());

        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 3 TextViews )
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

please help i cant move ahead without solving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have ypu checked if your adapted't getCount returns not 0?

Comment: any error in logcat ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Json String is not correct

```
private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE="incorrect json"
```

Please verify it on online validator[like the one you can see in inline screenshot] and parse it.
[image]

Comment: i dont know much about json do you have any idea what could be wrong in this script. cause i copied the script from a Udacity cource link is here https://gist.github.com/udacityandroid/10892631f57f9f073ab9e1d11cfaafcf

Comment: please try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the mistake I was making, the JSON code is correct. I was using

```
JSONArray earthquakeArray = BaseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("Features");
```

insted of

```
JSONArray earthquakeArray = BaseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("features");
```

because my JSON script has a key named "features" not "Features".

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your json.
Try parsing it by just taking two dummy variables.

PS : check the image alongside. Json doesn't looks appropriate.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi7or.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove '\' this slash from complete JSON string you've copied from the source.
This will make you JSON string valid and your JSONObject calls will easily able to understand and parse what you want to say.
Use json validator like [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Here is first object of your json without \ slashes to demonstrate you've have to do it like this:

> {     "type": "FeatureCollection",    "metadata": {       "generated":
>   1462295443000,        "url":
>   "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10",
>         "title": "USGS Earthquakes",        "status": 200,      "api": "1.5.2",
>         "limit": 10,        "offset": 1,        "count": 10     },  "features": [{
>         "type": "Feature",      "properties": {             "mag": 7.2,             "place":
>   "88km N of Yelizovo, Russia",             "time": 1454124312220,          "updated":
>   1460674294040,            "tz": 720,          "url":
>   "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004vvx",
>             "detail":
>   "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004vvx&format=geojson",
>             "felt": 2,          "cdi": 3.4,             "mmi": 5.82,            "alert": "green",
>             "status": "reviewed",           "tsunami": 1,           "sig": 798,             "net":
>   "us",             "code": "20004vvx",             "ids":
>   ",at00o1qxho,pt16030050,us20004vvx,gcmt20160130032510,",          "sources":
>   ",at,pt,us,gcmt,",            "types":
>   ",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,",
>             "nst": null,            "dmin": 0.958,          "rms": 1.19,            "gap": 17,
>             "magType": "mww",           "type": "earthquake",           "title": "M 7.2 -
>   88km N of Yelizovo, Russia"       },      "geometry": {           "type": "Point",
>             "coordinates": [158.5463, 53.9776, 177]         },      "id": "us20004vvx"
>     }]
>
> }

You can copy this object and verify in JSON validator or directly try to parse it will work.

Hope this helps and solves your prob.